# I want to sort my listview according to date in this formate ? in java android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a question my date formate is d mmm,yyyy how I can sort this? 
FORMAT d mmm,yyyy
I want to sort my list with a date anyone help me please in this formate how I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you set your adapter do these changes.You can use your list model data

Recent data come into top  if you want reverse change this   `return date2s.compareTo(date1);` into   `return date1.compareTo(date2s);` like that

```
   Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Result>() {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            @Override
            public int compare(Result t1, Result t2) {
                if (t1.getCreatedDate() != null) {
                    String sDate1 = t1.getCreatedDate();
                    String date2 = t2.getCreatedDate();
                    java.util.Date date1 = null;
                    Date date2s = null;
                    try {
                        date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("d mmm,yyyy").parse(sDate1);
                        date2s = new SimpleDateFormat("d mmm,yyyy").parse(date2);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (date1 != null && date2s != null) {
                        return date2s.compareTo(date1);
                    }
                    return 0;
                } else return 0;
            }
        });
```

Comment: t1.getcreateddata() where is this function? What is the Result in this code?

Comment: vacinelistitem vli=new vacinelistitem();
               vli.setNameofavacination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vacinename")));
                vli.setDateofacination(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vacinedate")));
               vli.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("vacinestatus")));
               vacination.add(vli);

Comment: here i am gatting dates from sqllite and set in a customelistview but my dates are not in a sorted form i want to sort it d mmm,yyyy formate

Comment: t1.getcreateddata()   this is your date and Result is your model

 String sDate1 = t1.getCreatedDate();//date 1 
 String date2 = t2.getCreatedDate();//date 2